# How can I transform my class in a function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a class using React.js and I am trying to have a function. Here is my class :

```
class Datepicker extends Component {
    state = { startDate: new Date() };

    setStartDate = (startDate) => {
      this.setState({startDate});
      this.props.handleDate(startDate);
    }

    render(){
        const {startDate} = this.state;

        return (
            <DatePicker
                className="custom-select"
                dateFormat="dd/MM/yyyy"
                selected={startDate}
                onChange={this.setStartDate}
            />
        )
    }
}
```

And here is what I tried :

```
const Datepicker = (props) => {
    const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(new Date());
    return (
        <DatePicker className="custom-select" dateFormat="dd/MM/yyyy" selected={startDate}
                    onChange=???/>
    );
};
```

I don't know how to continue with that function... could you help me please ?

Thank you very much !

Comment: Surely it's no different to the method in the class version? You want to update the state and call the prop.

Comment: I tried but without effects...

Comment: So **show that**, give a [mre], but `???` certainly won't work.

Answer (score 1):

Simply define another function inside your functional component:

```
const Datepicker = (props) => {
  const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(new Date());

  const onChange = (startDate) => {
    setStartDate(startDate);
    props.handleDate(startDate);
  };

  return (
    <DatePicker
      className="custom-select"
      dateFormat="dd/MM/yyyy"
      selected={startDate}
      onChange={onChange}
    />
  );
};
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use effects to call props.handleDate?

Comment: props.handleDate is a callback function passed from the parent component which should trigger only when there is change in date .

Comment: @RinkeshGolwala why you think it would be better?